# How can I say "if width > height" then "do this" with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have a few elements. The number of them on the page changes constantly, keep that in mind.

The element is called **.portalimg**. I need to say if the `width > height`, set it's `width` to 125px. If the `height > width`, set the `height` to 125px.

Here's what I have:

```
$('.portalimg').each(function() {
  var pimgw = $(this).width();
    var pimgh = $(this).height();
    if (pimgw > pimgh) {
        $(this).css('width','125px')
    } else {
        $(this).css('height','125px')
    }
});
```

EDIT: It alerts success but doesn't apply the `width` & `height`.
Where did I go wrong?

EDIT 2: Updated code with cleanest from below. That still only constrains the height property, even if the images is taller then it is wide. Take a look:

http://jacksongariety.com/gundoglabs/

EDIT 3: The issue is they all return 0. If I have an alert say the value of pimgw or pimgh, it's always 0.

**EDIT 4: Finally got the best, cleanest code possible with caching and it'll always load correctly, even if it draws images form the cache:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.portalimg').ready(function(){
        $('.portalimg').fadeTo(0,1).each(function(index) {
            var a = $(this);
            if (img.width() > a.height()) {
                a.css('width','135px')
            } else {
                a.css('height','125px')
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i think for (pimg in body) should be for (pimg in pgbody)

Comment: Yeah, now it alerts success but doesn't constrain anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are multiple elements of class portalimg you could simply use a .each iterator: http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$(function() {
    $('.portalimg').each(function(index) {
        var img = $(this);
        if (img.width() > img.height()) {
            img.css('width','125px')
        } else {
            img.css('height','125px')
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This works! The (index) does it. But my first image is returning 0 for some reason.

Comment: It's grabbing the variables before the page has a change to load!

Comment: So the width is 0 when the page loads. How can I make it wait till all the images have loaded?

Comment: @JacksonGariety is your code within a ready call as per my edit? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work. But cool bit of jQuery I found did: $('.portalimg').load(function(){

Comment: you're not caching `$(this)`, so you're building a new jQuery object 4 times per `.portalimg`

Comment: How can I prevent that re-building?

Comment: @JacksonGariety see my update, var img = $(this) = the cached object

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.portalimg').each(function() {
  var pimgw = $(this).width();
    var pimgh = $(this).height();
    if (pimgw > pimgh) {
        $(this).css('width','125px')
    } else {
        $(this).css('height','125px')
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks like you just copied from @Jesse's answer, and removed `this`.

Comment: This only constrain the height. :/

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$('.portalimg').each(function() {
    (($(this).width() > $(this).height())
    && ($(this).css('width','125px')) )
    || ($(this).css('height','125px'))
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Qx4jF/

Comment: Doesn't work. Looks like you meant to put an if statement somewhere in here.

Comment: `( ()&&() ) &&()` is a short-hand form of `if(){}else{}`

Comment: Aha, didn't know that! This doesn't constrain them at all though. But upvote for teaching me something cool.

Comment: Sorry, i meant `( ()&&() ) || ()`. Just be very caution when using it, they might sometimes break, since they are considered [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and they depend on the boolean that the function return. It breaks when the function inside doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is wrong you should use

```
pimg = $('.portalimg').each( function() {;
    alert("success")
    var pimgw = $(this).width();
    var pimgh = $(this).height();
    if (pimgw > pimgh) { 
        $(this).css('width','125px')
    } else {
        $(this).css('height','125px')
    }
});
```

This call a function on all find object with the class '.portalimg' in your document.

Comment: This only constrains the height no matter what.

Comment: you can try with maxWidth or check with Google Chrome and the script debuger if you get a good value for your width, some time is returning 0 if not set in code before.

Comment: Yeah, pimgw is always returning 0 for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to do your code later in the rendering of the page. Try the JQuery document loaded event for running your script.

Comment: Tried that, that makes it fire when it finished fetching the images, but is still displays 0 as the variable because the actual <img /> element still has nothing in it.

Comment: $(function(){}) doesn't work I mean. But setTimeout(fn(),5000) works fine.

Comment: Can you use the with of your parent instead if your parent is wrapping your image, it should get the same width as the image.

Comment: you should really cache `$(this)`.. you're building a new jQuery object every single time you use `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

Might try this. Other answers are excellent to. You went wrong with the syntax of for and with body. Did you mean #body or .body?

```
$(".portalimg").each(function(){ 

    var pimgw = $(this).width(),
        pimgh = $(this).height();

    if (pimgw > pimgh) {
        $(this).css('width','125px')
    }else{
        $(this).css('height','125px')
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd like to try and keep as much javascript as possible, but yes, this works.

Comment: Also, 'body' is a valid HTML element, no class or id is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.portalimg').each(function() { var
    img = $(this),
    w = img.width(),
    h = img.height(),
    toModify = w > h ? 'width' : 'height';
    img.css(toModify, '125px');
}
```